# How to continue this problem

Tags: integration

Prove that $\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{1}{n} \sin \dfrac{t}{n} + \sin \dfrac {2t}{n} + ... + \sin \dfrac{(n-1)t}{n}  = \dfrac{1 - \cos \space t}{t}$

I have obtained that $\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{1}{n} \displaystyle \sum ^n _{k=1} \sin \dfrac{kt}{n} = \displaystyle \int_0 ^t \sin x \space dx = 1 - \cos \space t $, but I don't know how to get from this answer that 
I have obtained that $\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{1}{n} \displaystyle \sum ^{n-1} _{k=1} \sin \dfrac{kt}{n} =  \dfrac {1 - \cos t}{t} $

Comment: Sorry, integral of what? Isn't a parenthesis missing from the first line?

Comment: @Berci I think I've corrected all of the typos

Comment: The limits of $(1/n)\sum^n$ and $(1/n)\sum^{n-1}$ are the same if one of them exists. So there must be something wrong with what you have obtained. And it is still unclear what the integral sign means here.

Comment: @julien the integral of sin x dx from 0 to t

Comment: Then there is a mistake, see muzzlator's answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are right in noticing this is a Riemann sum calculation however

$$ \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^n \sin{\frac{k t}{n}} = \int_0^1 \sin(xt) dx = \left[\frac{-\cos{xt}}{t} \right]^1_0 $$

Edit: I suppose I should mention where you made the mistake.  If you are integrating from $0$ to $t$, you need to take step sizes of $\frac{t}{n}$, not $\frac{1}{n}$.

Comment: So you could obtain the correct answer integrating from 0 to t?

Comment: Yes you can, but the factor of $\frac{1}{n}$ outside should change to $\frac{1}{t} \frac{t}{n}$.  The $\frac{t}{n}$ term will go into the Riemann sum, the $\frac{1}{t}$ term will be left outside.

Comment: Hmm, I see what I did wrong thanks to you

Comment: Wait, I still don't quite understand it. Why is $\int_0^1 \sin(xt) dx = \left[\frac{-\cos{xt}}{t} \right]^1_0 $? I doesn't seem true to me. Also, this isn't the final answer, so what steps do I need to make after this one, I'm pretty confused

Comment: @Homework: the part you are missing is that the LHS with the sum is equal to $\frac{1}{t} \int_{0}^{t}  \sin x dx = \int_{0}^{1} \sin (tx) dx$